# mysql: checking order of data

Tags: mysql

I have run into a situation where there is 'bad' data in a number of tables. Data has been cross contaminated from various sources and I need to clean it out.

Specifically there are several hundred tables with identical definitions. They hold timed sensor data with an auto-increment column, Time/Date stamp and other data. The 'bad' data can be identified by time/date jumping backwards rather than growing as expected.

Example:

```
10 2010/01/05 
11 2010/01/06
12 2010/01/07
13 2008/05/09
14 2008/05/10
15 2008/05/11
16 2010/01/08
17 2010/01/09
```

Im looking for the best way to find these areas.

Some things to note:
   - the tables in question have 100s of millions of records
   - in my example the dates are sequential - in reality there may be 10 or 1000 entries for a given date (with timestamps on each) and then nothing for a week.

I can imagine a perl script walking through each and looking for these jumps. Im wondering if there is a faster, more sql-esque method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select t.* from t, (select @maxDate := '') init
where not if(date > @maxDate, @maxDate := date, 0)
order by id
```

This is the fastest way I can think of.

NOTE: I'm assuming you're expecting to get records with IDs `13, 14, 15` in your example.

Comment: I changed the 'date > @maxDate' to a '>=' but otherwise it seems to work v well. TY.